# CSS Foundation making left div go below right div on small screens

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have a layout with a header where I have a `title bar`, and two divs. Div on left takes up `4 columns` on big screens and the one on right takes `8 columns`. The one on right has an image that takes up the whole div's width. On small screens I would like the left div to go below right div, but the problems is that on the small screens left div disappears under the right div.
This is the html:

```
<div class="header row row-wrapper">
    <div class="frontpage-header-content">
      <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <div class="large-4 medium-12 columns lcol">
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <div class="border"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="large-8 medium-12 columns rcol">
        <div class="hero-image-wrapper">
          <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="header-title-bar">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
          <div class="title-bar">
            <div class="title-bar-left">
              <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-open="offCanvasLeft"></button>
              <span class="title-bar-title">Meny</span>
            </div>
            <div class="title-bar-right">
              <span class="title-bar-title">Støtteforeningen for Kreftrammede</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.header -->
```

And this is the css:

```
.header-title-bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.header .columns {
    padding-right: 0;
}

.hero-image-wrapper .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 16px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
}

@include breakpoint(medium down) {
    .row-wrapper{
       width :100%;
       display: flex;
       flex-flow: row wrap;
    }
    .lcol{
       float:left;
       order: 2;
    }
    .rcol{
       float:right;
       order: 1;
    }
}
```

This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ekcfq38u/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the text to be on the left on large screens but underneath on small, you need to use [`push` and `pull` source ordering](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#source-ordering) provided by foundation.

Note, I had to reorder your `html` and place the `div` containing text underneath the image.

https://jsfiddle.net/ru36n61v/

Comment: I am not getting the wanted result on my page, image is getting smaller and the right div is not taking the full width, but I will accept your answer and post another question for it

Comment: I managed to recreat the problem that I have on my page, this is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ru36n61v/8/ I will make post a new question for it

Comment: this is where the new question is:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258491/css-pulling-div-below-the-other-one-not-working-on-small-screens

Answer (score 0):

In foundation grid you can add "pull" and "push" classes to your grid columns so that "you can shift columns around between breakpoints". Its called [Source Ordering](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#source-ordering).

For Example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-8 large-push-4">
      this goes to the right on large screens.
  </div>
  <div class="large-4 large-pull-8">
      this goes to the left.
  </div>
</div>
```

On smaller screen because we have added the left div's code below the right one it will naturally be displayed below.

I have updated your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ekcfq38u/2/) so that the left div goes below the right div.